# Convert Local Excel.xlsx File to Google spreadsheet Google DRIVE API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to convert a local Excel.xlsx file with all existent design, format and formulas existent in my local Excel file. How can I do that using Google API with PHP?
What I was doing but not working was :

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Name');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/credentials.json');
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $fileID = '';
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/files/';
    $fileName = 'MAIN.xlsx';//this is the file I want to convert to Google sheet
    $filePathName = $path.$fileName;

    $mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
    $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

    $createdFile = $service->files->copy($file, array(
        'data' => $filePathName,
        'mimeType' => $mimeType,
        'convert' => true,
    ));
```

But that is not working. How should I correct?

Comment: See similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38686243/14606045) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686490/14606045)

Comment: I get this error when I try that: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Resource_Files::insert() in...` For some reason it says the "insert" on this line `$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, $insertArray);` does not exist

Comment: can you add the modified script you were trying to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a XLSX file from the local PC to Google Document.
- When the XLSX file is uploaded, you want to convert it to Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the method of "Files: copy" is used. This method copies the file on Google Drive. So I think that this cannot be used for achieving your goal. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- From your error message, I thought that you might be using Drive API v3. I guess that this might be also the reason of your issue.

From above points, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your $client here.

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/files/';
$fileName = 'MAIN.xlsx';//this is the file I want to convert to Google sheet
$filePathName = $path.$fileName;

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('MAIN.xlsx');
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet');
$data = file_get_contents($filePathName);
$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
printf("%s\n", $createdFile->getId());
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already been able to get and out values for Google Drive using Drive API. Please be careful this.
- In this method, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this. When you want to upload the large file, please use the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

#### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Create files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/create-file)

Comment: @ichiro suzuki Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved.